# Код не работает, помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовал API, но когда хочу задать параметры, чтобы вывести их в другом файле Card.js машина говорит, что я ошибся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за того, что ты используешь didMount, компонент сначала рендерится, а потом только заполняет state. У тебя пустой массив и первый элемент, естественно, недоступен. Либо делай запрос в componentWillMount, либо проверяй не пустой ли массив.

Comment: componentWillMount теперь deprecated